# Keyboard shortcuts iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm implementing keyboard shortcuts into mine iOS app.

Should I have shortcuts like <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> or just a simple <kbd>n</kbd>?

Other example for navigation: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> or just <kbd>1</kbd>?

*Btw, I'm new to User Experience so I hope this is an valid question here?*

Comment: If you can clarify why you have concerns about how you are implementing the keyboard shortcuts the way you intend to, it might help with getting the answers that you are looking for rather than general feedback.

Comment: I may be wrong but... I don't thing there is a cmd (or whatever that sign is) button in iOS. http://chrisbowler.s3.amazonaws.com/personal/posts/2012/mail.png

Comment: @BartGijssens keyboard shortcuts for iOS are available when the user connects a bluetooth keyboard to the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, typically, in most applications these shortcuts are used with tabulated/object-oriented frameworks.

A good example of this is Chrome and how pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> will open a new window. As such, it would be best to replicate this very same functionality.

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> is used to change to the first tab in chrome. As such, try and replicate this as well.

As for other commands, try and see how some of the other major market programs like Google and Sublime do it. If you do the same, you should be perfectly fine.